# Java Migration Application context xml to @Beans

Tags: java, spring

Im trying to convert my context xml of hikari db setting to Beans method

```
<bean id="proxyConfig"
      factory-bean="proxyConfigSupport"
      factory-method="create"/>

<bean id="proxyConfigSupport" class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.support.ProxyConfigSpringXmlSupport">
    <property name="dataSourceName" value="dataSourceDefaultName"/>
    <property name="queryListener" ref="queryListener"/>
</bean>
```

Im trying to understand how to convert it so I tried this way

```
@Bean(name = "proxyConfigSupport")
public ProxyConfigSpringXmlSupport proxyDataSource(ChainListener queryListener) {
    ProxyConfigSpringXmlSupport proxyConfigSpringXmlSupport = new ProxyConfigSpringXmlSupport();
    proxyConfigSpringXmlSupport.setDataSourceName("dataSourceDefaultName");
    proxyConfigSpringXmlSupport.setQueryListener(queryListener);
    return proxyConfigSpringXmlSupport;
}
```

But what does it mean **"proxyConfig" factory-bean="proxyConfigSupport"**
How do i set it the same ?

```
@Bean(name = "proxyConfig")
    public ProxyConfig proxyConfig(ProxyConfigSpringXmlSupport proxyConfigSpringXmlSupport) {
        ProxyConfig proxyConfig = new ProxyConfig();
        return proxyConfig;
            /*
        <bean id="proxyConfig"
          factory-bean="proxyConfigSupport"
          factory-method="create"/>

     */
    }
```

Comment: It means nothing more than `proxyConfigSpringXmlSupport.create()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets divide the XML up into sections.

```xml
<bean id="proxyConfigSupport" class="net.ttddyy.dsproxy.support.ProxyConfigSpringXmlSupport">
    <property name="dataSourceName" value="dataSourceDefaultName"/>
    <property name="queryListener" ref="queryListener"/>
</bean>
```

You already got that bean method

```java
@Bean
public ProxyConfigSpringXmlSupport proxyConfigSupport(ChainListener queryListener) {
    ProxyConfigSpringXmlSupport proxyConfigSpringXmlSupport = new ProxyConfigSpringXmlSupport();
    proxyConfigSpringXmlSupport.setDataSourceName("dataSourceDefaultName");
    proxyConfigSpringXmlSupport.setQueryListener(queryListener);
    return proxyConfigSpringXmlSupport;
}
```

Now the second one

```xml
<bean id="proxyConfig"
      factory-bean="proxyConfigSupport"
      factory-method="create"/>
```

Is nothing more then a description of what should take place. It defines a [`FactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) and specifies it do delegate the `getObject()` to the `proxyConfigSupport` bean and call the `create()` method. This is also explained in the [Spring Framework Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method).

As an `@Bean` method is also, kind of, a factory for beans, you can do something like this.

```java
@Bean
public ProxyConfig proxyConfig(ProxyConfigSpringXmlSupport proxyConfigSupport) {
  return proxyConfigSupport.create();
}
```

Nothing more and nothing less.